# How to modify toml file in cpp (TOML++)

Tags: c++, toml

I am using toml++. How can I modify a particular value of a TOML file in CPP using toml++

```
json ConfigService::getAllData(std::string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        auto _data_table = toml::parse_file(filePath);
        _data_table["config_paths"]["DIAAI_core"] = "diaaiSetting.toml";  # this is not working
        cout << _data_table << endl;
    }
    catch (const exception err)
    {
        std::cerr << "Parsing failed:\n"
                  << err.what() << "\n";
        std::runtime_error(err.what());
    }
}
```

##### traceback

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘toml::v3::node_view<toml::v3::node>’ and ‘int’)
   51 |         _data_table["config_paths"] = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

For a few days, I had this issue as well and looked into many ways of trying to set values using toml++. What I've come up with can be a temporary solution, but it works pretty decently.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <toml++/toml.hpp>
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

int main() {
    static constexpr auto source = R"(
        [config_paths]
        DIAAI_core = [""]
    )"sv;
    toml::table _data_table      = toml::parse(source);

    if (toml::array* arr = _data_table["config_paths"]["DIAAI_core"].as_array()) {
        arr->for_each([](auto&& el) {
            if constexpr (toml::is_string<decltype(el)>)
                if(el == "")
                    el = "diaaiSetting.toml"sv;
        });
    }
    std::cout << _data_table << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}

output: 
[config_paths]
DIAAI_core = [ 'diaaiSetting.toml' ]
```

The value itself is not a string, but an array of strings that just holds one value, so deserializing it should be fairly easy.

You can interact with values easily in [toml11](https://github.com/ToruNiina/toml11) so you may want to take a look at that if this does not suit you.